# How to create virtual registry for certain programs?

Tags: windows, windows-registry

Is there a way to create a virtual Registry and force only certain programs to use this one?
Or to create a virtual Registry but which i can shut down (this registry will be only used while i activate it)?!

Or redirect all querys to another place in the registry

Open for any help.
Appreciate your help.

Greetings.

Comment: I don't know if it redirects registry calls per-se, but you might want to have a look at [Sandboxie](http://www.sandboxie.com/).

Comment: Thats not what i'm really looking for: more like this: http://www.boxedapp.com/boxedappsdk/help/index/virtual_registry.html but this costs too much.

Answer (score 1):

Use boxedapp or boxedapppacker. this is the best solution.

BoxedAppSDK_CreateVirtualRegKey
The function creates a virtual registry key.
Its arguments are similar to the arguments of the winapi function RegCreateKeyEx.
[C++]
LONG __stdcall BoxedAppSDK_CreateVirtualRegKey(
HKEY hKey,
LPCTSTR lpSubKey,
DWORD Reserved,
LPCTSTR lpClass,
DWORD dwOptions,
REGSAM samDesired,
LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSecurityAttributes,
PHKEY phkResult,
LPDWORD lpdwDisposition
);

And many other features. Great SDK.